# Xamarin forms: How to change the listview scrolling behavior to bottom to top?

Tags: listview, scroll, xamarin.forms

I have a listview in my xamarin forms project which contains the latest item on top. When scroll to bottom I can view the remaining items.

**Now I need to show the recent item on the bottom and when scroll up need to show the remaining items? The same like WhatsApp chat window.**

How can I do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this we are going to rotate the ListView and ViewCells main layout to 180 degrees so that the list start from the bottom but by doing this the scroll bar now will appear at the left side. To fix that we are going to use the property `FlowDirection` (Released in the version 3.0 of Xamarin Forms).

So in the ListView we are going to set these two properties:

```
FlowDirection="RightToLeft"
Rotation="180"
```

And in the view cells main layout:

```
FlowDirection="LeftToRight"
Rotation="180"
```

Be aware that now that the ListView and ViewCells are rotated so you should consider that the bottom of your ListView is at the top.

For more read [this](https://www.xamboy.com/2018/07/09/exploring-a-chat-ui-in-xamarin-forms-part-2/)

Comment: Hi, I have tried above solution, it work's fine in ios platform but when I try in xamarin.forms WPF, listview scrollbar visible in the right side of the listview. please suggest any idea.

Comment: I don't know anything more about this, for more details please go through the article that I have provided in the answer. If you get any solution please update it here.

Comment: @Deepak Did you get any solution for this?

Comment: @SreejithSree Hi bro, I am implementing a chat UI according to the link provided by you. I got that problem with scrolling the list view in android pie. Did you have a solution for that?

Comment: @AndroDevil No bro, still I have that problem. If you get any solution please update it here also.

Comment: @SreejithSree Bro, They reported the bug https://github.com/xamarin/Xamarin.Forms/issues/7166

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest adding a timestamp or index property to your items (anything that allows you to determine a way on how to sort them (also define "using Linq;" at the top of your view.xaml.cs file).

Then when setting your ListView's Itemssource you can say:

```
ListView.ItemsSource = models.OrderBy(entry => entry.TimeStamp);
```

If you use DataBinding, you can alternatively add a Property to your view to return your models in the same way:

```
public List<EntryModel> SortedEntryList
{
    get { return entrymodels.OrderBy(entry => entry.TimeStamp); }
}
```

I am assuming that you have some sort of List or ObservableCollection you are adding to the ListView.

Comment: Very simpl to reverse the listview, please see the accepted answer.